# Remove certificate from old server and install on new server

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, web-hosting

We host a website in our company.

A certificate was issued to www.ourdomainname.com from the company IT department.

Now we want to move the website to azure and install the certificate there.

I already exported the certificate with private key exported set to true from the server.

**1.)** What will happen when the certificate is installed on azure when it is also installed on our company server?

**2.)** What will happen when the website on our server is stopped in the server and the certificate is then imported to the azure website?

**3.)** How can I guarantee a soft transition time without any break?

The **aim** is:

Website on the company server going to be deleted and the website on azure is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen when the certificate is installed on azure when it is also installed on our company server?

web site will be available via SSL in Azure too.

> What will happen when the website on our server is stopped in the server and the certificate is then imported to the azure website?

web site on your server will be inaccessble.

> How can I guarantee a soft transition time without any break?

it is more about DNS management. There is no much work with SSL. You just install SSL on both internal and Azure servers, so clients can access both. Test if web site on Azure works the same way as on your internal server. Then point all clients (via DNS) to a web site on Azure. When all clients move and there are no references to internal server, you can safely shutdown it.

Comment: I updated my question with the aim/purpose. Can you please still modify your answer then - if it is needed - , thanks :-)

Comment: From where do I know "when all clients moved and all references to the company/internal server are gone?

Comment: I mean DNS references. No DNS entry references internal web server. You can put a monitor on web site and see who still attempt to access it. Identify them and configure them to connect to Azure instead of internal server.

Comment: from 1.) "web site will be available via SSL in Azure too." Which site do the browsers visit, the site on company server or the site on azure? I prefer the latter of course.

Comment: Then do DNS work to change references from old to new web server.

Comment: So actually I could then install the certificate on azure, if it works that I successfully import it there I should disable/stop the website on the company server. This can happen within 1 minute actually.

Comment: Generally, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL Certificate which was exported from the current server has to be imported in Azure. The format of the certificate has to be PFX.

Now, in the DNS Management , you need to edit the A record for the URL and point it to the IP address of Azure. This will make sure that any request made will be handled by Azure .

Comment: When the A record for  www.mydomainname.com points to the IP address which azure ip address should I choose ? Its dynamic... OR should I first add the certificate to the azure website to get that static ip and THEN let the dns guys change the A record to point to that new static ip? That would make sense at least.

Comment: Any comment to my last answer? :-)